# HTML table not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have an HTML table with JSON DATA,what i am doing is creating one column as input-field, my table headers are `Code`,`Item Name`,`Unitcode`,`Quantity`And `AcceptedQty` in which i am making Accepted Quantity only input field,but the Quantity Field also gets converted to Input-Field i don't know what i am doing wrong

```js
var tableDataDraft = [{
    "Code": "1326",
    "Item Name": "PINEAPPLE KG",
    "Unitcode": "NOS",
    "Quantity": "3.00",
    "AcceptedQty": "3.00"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1494",
    "Item Name": "2D CAKE CHARGES PER KG",
    "Unitcode": "NOS",
    "Quantity": "3.00",
    "AcceptedQty": "3.00"
  }
]


function addTableDraft(tableDataDraft) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableDataDraft[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.classList.add("text-center");
    tr.classList.add("head")
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableDataDraft.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input"); //creating input field hidden
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableDataDraft[i][col[j]];
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Code'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) { //now setting html attributes
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Item Name'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Unitcode'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Unit_code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Quantity'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) { //this quantity field i don't want to be input field

        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Quantity');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['AcceptedQty'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) { //this one i want to be a input field

        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "AcceptedQty");
        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
        quantityField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "tel");
        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      }

      if (j > 1)
        tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("table");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");



}

addTableDraft(tableDataDraft)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="table-responsive" id="commonDvScroll">
  <table id=table></table>
</div>
```

why that Quantity field is also showing up as input field i don't know

As my code is bit lengthy because i am adding HTML form `Attributes` because i want that all data to my back end,so i am serializing my form while ajax call

I have commented all the lines where i am doing what so that it will be easier for all of you to understand

Comment: 'why that Quantity field is also showing up as input field i don't know', it's because of this `var quantityField = document.createElement("input");`

Comment: @designtocode that one i have created to show `AcceptedQty` as input field here i am talking about `Quantity` input-field

Comment: @dheerajkumar It because the value of `Quantity` and `AcceptedQty` is the same

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i aslo think so,but the issue is the are going to same always one will be editable and other will be uneatable

Comment: @dheerajkumar the problem is with this section `tableDataDraft[i]['AcceptedQty'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]`. Try changing the value of `AcceptedQty` to 4 and it works. Also add a `table.innerHTML = tabledata` for the `Quantity` if block

Comment: @raghav710 but issue is when  page  will load initially both the columns are going to have same data

Comment: @dheerajkumar I've tried explaining my perspective in my answer. Let me know if that clarifies

Comment: @raghav710 let me check that once

Comment: @raghav710 hey sir i have a small doubt

Comment: @dheerajkumar sorry for the delay. Please ask your doubt

Comment: @raghav710 it is already cleared sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because while inserting values per row, you are comparing the *column values* instead of the *column name*. This will cause issues when the values are the same, for example `Quantity` and `AcceptedQty` have the same value `3.0`. Try changing one to `4.0` and you can notice that it works.

Here is a simplified version of your code that checks if the current column is `AcceptedQty` and shows an input field only for that. You can still have the other `if` blocks but make sure the condition is something like `if (col[j] === 'Code')` or `(col[j] === 'Quantity')` etc.

```js
var tableDataDraft = [{
    "Code": "1326",
    "Item Name": "PINEAPPLE KG",
    "Unitcode": "NOS",
    "Quantity": "3.00",
    "AcceptedQty": "3.00"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1494",
    "Item Name": "2D CAKE CHARGES PER KG",
    "Unitcode": "NOS",
    "Quantity": "3.00",
    "AcceptedQty": "3.00"
  }
]


function addTableDraft(tableDataDraft) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableDataDraft[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.classList.add("text-center");
    tr.classList.add("head")
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableDataDraft.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input"); //creating input field hidden
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableDataDraft[i][col[j]];
      if (col[j] === 'AcceptedQty') { 
      //this one i want to be a input field
        
        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "AcceptedQty");
        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
        quantityField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "tel");
        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      }
      else
       { //now setting html attributes
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      
      if (j > 1)
        tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("table");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");



}

addTableDraft(tableDataDraft)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="table-responsive" id="commonDvScroll">
  <table id=table></table>
</div>
```

Comment: hey can you please check this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846400/appended-new-row-is-not-behaving-like-previous-one-row

Answer (score 0):

Change how you are checking for the data returned. Instead of checking if the value is the same, check the data key like this

`if (col[j] === 'Quantity')`

Then you can insert data for this specific column or data key.

```js
var tableDataDraft = [{
    "Code": "1326",
    "Item Name": "PINEAPPLE KG",
    "Unitcode": "NOS",
    "Quantity": "3.00",
    "AcceptedQty": "7.00"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1494",
    "Item Name": "2D CAKE CHARGES PER KG",
    "Unitcode": "NOS",
    "Quantity": "3.00",
    "AcceptedQty": "10.00"
  }
]


function addTableDraft(tableDataDraft) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableDataDraft[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.classList.add("text-center");
    tr.classList.add("head")
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableDataDraft.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input"); //creating input field hidden
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableDataDraft[i][col[j]];
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Code'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) { //now setting html attributes
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Item Name'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Unitcode'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Unit_code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (col[j] === 'Quantity') { //this quantity field i don't want to be input field
        var quantityNoEdit = document.createElement("input");
        quantityNoEdit.style.border = "none";
        quantityNoEdit.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityNoEdit.setAttribute("name", "Quantity");
        quantityNoEdit.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
        quantityNoEdit.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
        quantityNoEdit.setAttribute("type", "tel");
        quantityNoEdit.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityNoEdit.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityNoEdit.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        quantityNoEdit.disabled = true;
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityNoEdit);
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Quantity');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        console.log('Quantity:' + tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['AcceptedQty'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) { //this one i want to be a input field

        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "AcceptedQty");
        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
        quantityField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "tel");
        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
        console.log('AcceptedQty:' + col[j]);
      }

      if (j > 1)
        tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("table");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");



}

addTableDraft(tableDataDraft)
```

```html
<table id="table"></table>
```